# How can I grab the date from the top of this csv?

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

Hi! I have this csv I'm trying to grab the date from using pandas. the date is located above the header in the picture above. I thought I could just grab row 3 but that doesn't seem to work. Here is my code. My goal is to convert that date into datetime so I can recognize what day I'm grabbing info from. The name of the csv unfortunately has the wrong date.

```
datetime_df = pd.read_csv(holdings_file)
print(datetime_df.row(3))
```

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'row'
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a value at a certain cell in a dataframe, you need to use `iat` rather than `row`. Also, if you want that date, you want the 3rd column not the 3rd row.

```py
datetime_df = pd.read_csv(holdings_file)
print(datetime_df.iat[0,3])
```

Comment: Oops! Yes, the third column! I ran that and still got an error.

'''    
raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 3

'''

Comment: Can you confirm the dimensions of your dataframe by printing them?